# How to implement the android viber app like voice record and send it to server?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I need to integrate the android voice recording to send to my other users. 
but it's should be within the mins. 
Any tutorials like android viber voice message like ?? 
I just need only the voice messages

I have checked but not find any tutorials or blog.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some people may have new to android so, if they trying to do these kind of app initially then you can help to them rather than this kind stupid vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Voice Message, but it's easy to create Audio VoIP Application. Just check [This Sample, which working throw Bluetooth](https://github.com/GensaGames/Sample-WebRTC)

**Update**

Since, you need just to send Audio message. Main plan to implement this is pretty simple. You need just to create Audio Voice recorder, to write some Voice message in file. [Just as example,](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm) but you can find a lot of other.  And then just transfer your file to the server, as byte array.

Comment: Thanks GensaGames, I am expecting to integrate small module for my application. just need 60s voice record and need to send it to the server.

Comment: @CarinaMj Answered.